# how to install kickstart in client system

Tags: nfs, kickstart

i am trying to install centos 5.3 with kickstart 
but it displaying "unable to download kickstart file. please modify the kickstart parameter"
what is the environment required in server to install kickstart in client through NFS

Answer (score 1):

Get on a working centos box.

`yum install system-config-kickstart`

go thru the app and set all the options you require, including your installation tree. ie: nfs://10.10.10.10/centos (personally I use an FTP server)

save the config file and put it on a web server somewhere.

get the "netinstall" image of centos 5.4/3, when at the CentOS splash screen type

`linux ks=http://foo.bar/kickstartfile.cfg`

That's it. Make sure the host computer has an active uplink and can receive a DHCP address of course! :P

Answer (score 0):

your server should have a installation source (copy of the cds/dvds or mounted isos) mountable via nfs and a directory with your kickstart files, also mountable via nfs.
for more details, take a look at the rhel documentation:
http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/sysadmin-guide/index.html
or this how-to:
http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/KickStart-HOWTO.html

but it could be your client environment is not setup correctly:

- is your network setup correct?
- can the client get through to your kickstart server?
- is dns resolution setup correctly on the client?

hope this helps you to get started.